# Dividing a file through shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to divide a file in chunks of 64MB. I want to find out no. of parts through shell script. My script is giving following error:
 line 3: 134M: value too great for base (error token is "134M")
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split -b 64m yourfile`. It will split your file into chunks for you named xa, xb, xc, etc.

Edit in response to your comment:

You can take the ceiling of the quotient of the file size and 64mb, that will give you the number of files required if the maximum file size is 64mb. The last file might be less than 64mb though.

One liner might look like:

`stat -f %z yourfile | perl -pi -e 'use POSIX; $_ = ceil $_ / (64 * 1024 * 1024);'`

Comment: Actually I want to find out the no of chunks of 64M the file can be divided into

Comment: I want to find out floor of the quotient

Comment: Does your file divide exactly into 64mb?

Comment: sorry there was some misunderstanding. Your command and your option both worked

Answer (score 2):

```
file=foo
chunks=$(echo "$(wc -c < "$file") / (64*10^6)" | bc -l)
```

or

```
file=foo
chunks=$(echo "$(wc -c < "$file") / (2^26)" | bc -l)
```

Depending on whether 64MB means 64000000 or 67108864 to you. Omit the -l if you want a truncated integer.

Comment: I think `wc -c` will read the whole file counting characters even though it doesn't need to. `stat` is better but otherwise your solution is good to. +1

Comment: @sjr: `wc` is more widely available. Many systems don't have `stat`. Also, as a test, I timed `wc -c file` versus `wc -c < file` on three different files sized 26 bytes, 948894 bytes and 1620547734 bytes (six tests). The time was the same for all of them. Using `strace` reveals that it calls `fstat64()` (some genius probably thought that was a good idea). On the other hand, `wc -w` and `wc -l` *do* have to read the whole file. Also, AWK would be another way to do the math in addition to `bc` or Perl.

Comment: Nice. I rescind my statement then :)